# Does an infinite random sequence contain all finite sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, random, infinity

If we have a finite alphabet, with each letter having a non-zero probability of being selected, will an infinite sequence of letters selected from that alphabet contain all finite sequences of letters in the alphabet?

What is the dis/proof for this?

Comment: The prove this you just need to add: 1) the letters occurrences are independent (some weaker condition also can work, but I guess this is your scenario) 2) add the words "with probability one" ('almost surely') to "will an infinite.. contain..."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, infinitely many times. This is called the [Infinite monkey theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem) and it seems there are nearly as many proofs on the web as one could expect if an infinite collection of monkeys were busy typing them frantically on their typewriters/computers for an infinite amount of time.

Answer (score 7):

Letters are selected independently?  Then the answer is YES.  Look in a textbook for results on "independent" sequences for hints on how to prove it.  For example, I might use the Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Comment: One should mention that this is an "almost surely" result, i.e. the event "only" happens with probability $1$.

Comment: Of course it's "almost surely".  Omitting a certain letter from your infinite sequence is an event of probability zero, not an empty event.

Answer (score 1):

I think there has to be at least one answer that says no. The question, as stated doesn't exclude from the event space sequences that consist, for example, of only one unique letter repeated infinite amount of times. The probability of getting such a string is indeed $0$, but the event is possible.