# Prove that it is almost certain that decimal expansion of a random number in the interval $[0, 1]$ contains all possible finite sequences of digits.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

As in the title - I look for a proof that it is almost certain that decimal expansion of a random number in the interval $[0, 1]$ contains all possible finite sequences of digits.

I know that taking random number in the interval $[0, 1]$ we will almost certainly pick a irrational one. But how do I prove that decimal expansion of irrational number contains all possible finite sequences of digits?

Or is there any other way to prove the statement in the title?

Now I think that maybe it may be somehow derived from Borel–Cantelli lemma.

Edit: it looks like that: [https://w3.math.uminho.pt/~scosentino/teaching/tm_MMTCEBES_2016-17/lecturenotes_tm.pdf](https://w3.math.uminho.pt/%7Escosentino/teaching/tm_MMTCEBES_2016-17/lecturenotes_tm.pdf) (on the 9th page).

Comment: This is a much stronger statement than being irrational. You can prove almost all numbers are irrational with a cardinality argument, but you can't prove this with a cardinality argument.

Comment: Did you try to prove it for just one digit? This may give you ideas to generalize.

Comment: I didn't - I don't know how. But as I am researching more and more about it I think that maybe it can be proven with Borel–Cantelli lemma @Somos.

Comment: On a similar note as Somos' comment: have you seen a proof that the Cantor set has Lebesgue measure zero?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73355/does-an-infinite-random-sequence-contain-all-finite-sequences

Comment: Have you looked at that link?

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I've already figured this question out by myself. Later I will post the answer.

Comment: OK, I'm looking forward to seeing your answer.