# Does an infinite random sequence contains (in)finitely many time its prefixes?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity

Consider an infinite random sequence $S=[i_1, i_2, ...]$ built with digits 0 to 9 (or any other alphabet). Every digit has a probability > 0 to be picked each time.

Consider a prefix of $S$, $S_k$ the finite sequence of $k$ elements from the first element to the $k$ element of $S$

$S_k$ = $[i_1,...,i_k]$

Suppose there exist some values of $k$ such that:

$S_{2k}$ = $[i_1, ...i_{2k}]$ = $[i_1, ..., i_k, i_1, ..., i_k]$ = $S_k^\frown S_k$

($^\frown$ is the concatenation operation.)

Define $S$ as ***birbant*** if $S_{2k}$ has the property to be equal to $S_k^\frown S_k$, with $k > m, m \in \mathbb{N}$ for any value of $m$.

Define $S$ as ***anti-birbant*** if *does not exist* any $S_{2k}$ that has the property to be equal to $S_k^\frown S_k$, with $k > m, m \in \mathbb{N}$ for any value of $m$.

Define $S$ as ***semi-birbant*** if $S_{2k}$ has the property to be equal to $S_k^\frown S_k$, with $k > m, m \in \mathbb{N}$ for any $m < C$, and does not exist any $S_{2k}$ that has the property to be equal to $S_k^\frown S_k$ for $k > m$ when $m >= C$.
With $C$ costant $ > 3$.

When $S$ is *semi-birbant*, there are $n$ $2k$-prefixes that have the above property, $S$ is also defined as ***n-semi-birbant*** .

> What is the probability that any $S$ is *birbant, anti-birbant* or *semi-birbant* ?

> Is there any predominance of a particular class *n-semi-birbant* classes for any $S$, or is it possible to compute an expected value of n ?

> Does this depend on the size of the alphabet?

*Example 1* (a pipe is inserted at the end of every $S_{2k}$):

```
S = 1,1|,2,1,1,2|,7,2,1,5,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,7,2,1,5,2| ...
```

We have:

- $S_2$ equal to $S_{1}^\frown S_{1}$
- $S_6$ equal to $S_{3}^\frown S_{3}$
- $S_{22}$ equal to $S_{11}^\frown S_{11}$

If no more prefixes repeats, this sequence is *semi-birbant* (*3-semi-birbant*)

If an infinite number of repetition of prefixes occurs, this sequence is *birbant*

*Example 2* (binary alphabet)

```
S = 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0...
```

The sequence is generated by start with 10 and double the ones on the front and the zeros at the end, then split the digits and concatenate to S and repeat.

This sequence is *not-birbant*.

---

Related: [Does an infinite random sequence contain all finite sequences?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73355/does-an-infinite-random-sequence-contain-all-finite-sequences)

Comment: The answer in the linked question is slightly misleading. It does not say that the monkeys _will_ type the collected works of Shakespeare. It just says they will [almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely) do so. So it is not _impossible_ that they won't, but the probability that they won't is zero. The same with your question: it is not _impossible_ that there won't be a concatenation of the prefix with itself - it is just _almost impossible_ (i.e. the probability is zero).

Comment: The statement of your question doesn't match the title. The statement appears to be about sequences whose first $2k$ elements comprise the concatenation of two identical subsequences (this has a definite non-zero probablity for each $k$).  Your title talks about something happening infinitely many times. Please clarify.

Comment: Nice problem, seems like yes, maybe use 0-1 Kolmogorov's law?

Comment: @RobArthan The statement as simple as possible: in any given infinite random sequence, does exist an infinite amount of prefixes with $2k$ elements such that the elements of the $2k$-prefixes is the concatenation of $k$-prefix with itself?

Comment: The notation in the body of your question is about **prefixes** of your sequence and are unclear: very specifically the words "an infinte amount" and "generate" don't make sense in context. Please clarify your question: examples would be helpful.

Comment: @RobArthan thanks for your suggestion. I've edited the body of the question to be a little more formal and inserted an example.

Comment: The property of sequences that you are now interested in is now much clearer, but it is still not clear exactly what you want to know. You can certainly construct sequences such that $S_{2k} = S_k \frown S_k$ for infinitely many $k$, but I suspect from what you say about probability that you want to know about probabilities rather than just existence? Am I right? If so, then, apart from the trivial case when there is only letter in the alphabet, then  I think the probability of a random sequence having this property is $0$.

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks again for your suggestion. I add some definition in the question in order to clarify what I am asking for. You are right, I ask for the probability that S has some property and if this depends on the size of the alphabet. In the end will be interesting to know which *n-semi-birbant* classes are much more prevalent than the others!

Comment: You could improve the clarity of your mathematical statements by using phrases such as "for all" and "for some."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume the random integers $\{I_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. equally likely over the 10-element set $\{0, ..., 9\}$ then
$$P[S_{2k}=[S_k:S_k]]=(1/10)^k \quad \forall k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$
and so
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P[S_{2k}=[S_k:S_k]] < \infty$$
Therefore, the Borel-Cantelli theorem says that, with probability 1, there are only a finite number of integers $k$ for which $S_{2k}=[S_k:S_k]$.

So (assuming I understand your definitions properly), the probability of being Birbant is zero.

You get a similar result if the alphabet size is any positive integer $m\geq 2$ (we do not require $m=10$). For $m\geq 2$ we have $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (1/m)^k<\infty$.